# Error install connect Python (My SQL 8.0.25)

Tags: python, mysql, mysqlconnector

Estoy instalando el conector de Python para My SQL por medio de My SQL Installer pero me sale un error al momento de instalarlo, me dice que no tiene los privilegios para poder entrar a cierta carpeta. Lo que no entiendo es que yo soy el usuario administrador del pc y solo está creada una sola cuenta local (que es la mia) he buscado instaladores independientes del conector en archivo MSI y me sale el mismo error. Espero puedan ayudarme con este problema.

LOG DEL INSTALLER

Comment: si vas a trabajar con python por que no instalar un modulo de este? (encontrados en pypi)

Comment: Si es Windows, Verifica que tienes el [pre-requisito](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html) VCredist 2015 o superior instalado. También puedes intentar con el [instalador independiente](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/8.0.html).